# Use a var in a var in Ansible (lookup) - aws_ssm plugin

Tags: variables, ansible, yaml

I'm trying to use a var in a var declaration on Ansible (2.7.10)

I'm using `aws_ssm` lookup plugin (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/aws_ssm.html)

Working example (hardcoded values):

```
var: "{{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/path/server00', region='eu-west-3') }}"
```

I want to use variables for the server name and the AWS region, but all my tentatives went on errors.

What I've tried so far:

```
var: "{{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/path/{{ server }}', region={{ region }}) }}"
```

```
var: "{{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/path/{{ server }}', region= + region) }}"
```

```
    - name: xxx
      debug: msg="{{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/path/{{ server }}', region='{{ region }}' ) }}"
      register: var
```

Without any success yet, thanks for your help,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never nest `{{...}}` template expressions. If you're already inside a template expression, you can just refer to variables by name.  For example:

```
var: "{{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/path/' + server, region=region) }}"
```

(This assumes that the variables `server` and `region` are defined.)

You can also take advantage of Python string formatting syntax. The following will all give you the same result:

- `'/path/' + server`
- `'/path/%s' % (server)`
- `'/path/{}'.format(server)`

And instead of `+` you can use the Jinja `~` concatenation operator, which acts sort of like `+` but forces arguments to be strings.  So while this is an error:

- `'some string' + 1`

This will result in the text `some string1`:

- `'some string' ~ 1`